# How to change my icon color based on what page is opened in react-native?

Tags: react-native

For example, this is my *Home* page. And i want *bottom bar- Home section* to be *blue* color.

Wherever i click on *bottom bar*, that page should open and the *icon color* should be blue

Here is the **related part of bottom bar**:

```
const FirstScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [color, setColor] = useState("#d4e6f1")

  const activeIcon = () =>{
    setColor("blue");
  }

return (
{/* Footer */}
      <View style={{
        position: "absolute",
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        bottom: 0,
        flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "space-around",
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
        height: 50,
      }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={activeIcon} style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 4, padding: 5, alignItems:"center" }}>
          <Home height={30} width={22} fill={color} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 4, padding: 5, alignItems: "center" }}>
          <Ratio height={30} width={22} fill={"#d6e8f2"} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 4, padding: 5, alignItems: "center"}}>
          <Time height={30} width={22} fill={"#d6e8f2"} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 4, padding: 5, alignItems: "center"}}>
          <User height={30} width={22} fill={"#d5e8f4"} />
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
)
export default FirstScreen;
```

[image]

Comment: can you show code of <Home /> or <Ratio /> or <Time /> or <User /> components?

Comment: they are  svg files. Is it needed? Cause i can set its color as in my first TouchableOpacity, `fill:{color}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect you want to achieving like this, if you click first tab, only the first tab's icon is blue, if you click second tab, only the second tab's icon is blue and so on

You can do by creating an index state

```
const [activeTabIndex, setActiveTabIndex] = useState(0)
```

then look on the onPress to change Index, also conditional rendering the fill color property by index

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setActiveTabIndex(0)} style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 4, padding: 5, alignItems:"center" }}>
  <Home height={30} width={22} fill={activeTabIndex == 0 ? "blue" : "#d4e6f1"} />
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setActiveTabIndex(1)} style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 4, padding: 5, alignItems: "center" }}>
  <Ratio height={30} width={22} fill={activeTabIndex == 1 ? "blue" : "#d6e8f2"} />
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setActiveTabIndex(2)} style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 4, padding: 5, alignItems: "center"}}>
  <Time height={30} width={22} fill={activeTabIndex == 2 ? "blue" : "#d6e8f2"} />
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setActiveTabIndex(3)} style={{ width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 4, padding: 5, alignItems: "center"}}>
  <User height={30} width={22} fill={activeTabIndex == 3 ? "blue" : "#d5e8f4"} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Edit:

If you want multiple actions on onPress you can do it like this for example

change `onPress={() => setActiveTabIndex(2)}`

to

```
onPress={() => {
  setActiveTabIndex(2)

  navigation.navigate("ThirdScreen")
}}
```

Comment: Thank you  Mr. Thats true I wanted to do this. But on my tabs, ill have also navigate onPress event. For example for Time icon, i added this `          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ThirdScreen")}`
So how can i use them together? is it possible to have two functions on onPress event? im not sure

Comment: Thank you a lot.  But color changing didn't work. I understood your code, it must work i think. So the problem may be with the icon components inside i guess. Thank you again :)